# Pivot like Excel in Python

Tags: python

I want to learn how to pivot data in Python like in Excel

Here is the data:

```
import pandas as pd 

`df = pd.DataFrame({
'country': ['Angola', 'India', 'Mongolia'],
1999: [800, 900, 1000],
2000: [800, 878, 900],
2001: [500, 345, 234],
2002: [400, 555, 666]
})
```

I want to pivot this dataset to have the country column appear vertically (i.e. see number of cases in each country each year)

Here is the code I am using:

```
df_melted = print(pd.melt(df, id_vars=['country'], var_name='year', value_name='value'))
```

Is this done correctly?

Comment: [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)